# setlocale() for date()/strftime() language full month name incorrect behaviour

Tags: php

The `strftime()` function according to [this](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) section of the PHP docs, should be used when trying to use a different language

> To format dates in other languages, you should use the setlocale() and
>   strftime() functions instead of date().

When using `setlocale()` with the following parameters

```
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES", 'Spanish_Spain', 'Spanish');
```

and `strftime()`

```
  $mes = strftime('%B', strtotime($semana->semana . "+{$diaPos} days"));
```

returns the month in english.

One solution I could approach is allocating a constant variable pointing the translations vs the months given by this function, so I would be able to return the correct name.

But it doesn't seem very elegant to me.

I'm using PHP7 on a debian based distro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use locale you need to have it generated in your system. On debian you should run as root:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

and then your script should work.

Comment: after restarting the apache2 service, this command worked. Thanks